# Adobe Air 3 on iOS: StageWebView viewport shrinks on double touch

Tags: ios, mobile, air, viewport

When I double touch the StageWebView on IPhone, it seems its viewport resizes (shrinks), even though I'm resetting the viewport on Stage Resize event:

`WView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this since I don't have an iPhone but:

The StageWebView is an HTML container that behaves like browsing from within the Safari browser on your iPhone. If you double tap on a website in Safari Mobile it zooms into the content. Perhaps that's what's happening with the StageWebView. If this is indeed the case then technically adjusting your viewport won't have any effect on the way the content is displaying. If you double tap on the content again it should resize back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Add viewport tag with user-scalable=no to your stagewebview's loaded url's head section.